# keep 100 newest file in a directory - windows script porting

Tags: windows, bash, shell, file, cmd

Hi: I have a cronjob in linux that keeps last 100 files in a directory, now I need to port it on windows.

my linux job is the following:

```
# sort by time, 1 per line | get files over 100th | delete those
$ ls -1t \my\path\tmp | tail --lines=+100 | xargs rm -f
```

and it's run once per day

Now I'm doing

```
REM  get files olther than 2D, delete
forfiles /d -2 /p "C:\my\path\tmp" /c "cmd /c Del @path"
```

that just deletes files older than 2 days, but I'd like not to delete files if total number is not too big (<100)

Comment: You could use for example `@for /F "skip=100 eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\my\path\tmp\*" /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do @del /A /F "C:\my\path\tmp\%%I"` posted in answers already several times. Open a command prompt window and run `del /?`, `dir /?` and `for /?` for help on these three [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) being all internal commands of Windows command processor `cmd.exe`.

Comment: This raises an interesting question: while working with `Forfiles`, you can access filename, path, filesize, ..., but what about the counter of your for-loop?

Comment: @Dominique Counter? There is no counter. __FOR__ is nearly always better than __FORFILES__ with one exception: `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` is used with option `/D`  to do something with files or folders newer or older than a specific date and `xcopy.exe` or `robocopy.exe` cannot be used for the task. However, __FORFILES__ always runs the specified __executable__ (important for internal *commands* of `cmd.exe`) and the executable has access to a copy of the environment variables as currently defined on starting the executable.

Comment: @Dominique It is of course not possible to count up an environment variable by started `cmd.exe` because this has no effect on the environment variables of parent process which started `cmd.exe`, i.e. `forfiles.exe` respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. No process can modify the environment variables of a parent process or any already running child process. If it would be possible for an executable to modify the memory used by another executable, it would be really a big security problem.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is not as cryptic and magical as using a for loop, but it works. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File |" ^
    "Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |" ^
    "Select-Object -Skip 100 |" ^
    "Remove-Item -WhatIf"
```

Powershell runs on Linux and Mac as well. https://github.com/powershell/powershell